# Mysterious auth failure only with MongoDB client on remote machines

Tags: mongodb

I can connect and authenticate normally using mongo client locally on the db server. I can not remotely. I can connect from a remote host, but db.auth always fails with the correct credentials that work locally, and also work remotely using the pymongo client. So this works:

```
> python
> import pymongo, config
> pymong.MongoClient(host=config.database_host)['live'].collection_names()
```

Yet this does not!

```
> mongo db.example.com/live
> db.auth('live', 'secret')
0
>
```

However, locally from the db server, the exact same thing does work, so I'm certain I'm using the right syntax and credentials :-(. What could possibly be going on here? In the server log I see:

```
2016-10-09T04:44:21.368+0000 I ACCESS   [conn22763]  authenticate db: live { authenticate: 1, nonce: "xxx", user: "live", key: "xxx" }
2016-10-09T04:44:21.368+0000 I ACCESS   [conn22763] Failed to authenticate live@live with mechanism MONGODB-CR: AuthenticationFailed: MONGODB-CR credentials missing in the user document
```

Perhaps it's a client version issue?

Answer (score 0):

I already answered it in the original post. It was a simple major version number mismatch between mongo client and server. This took me many hours to figure out because the error is straight up completely wrong, not to mention not even reported from the client I was trying, so had to dig it out of server logs.